# Renew iOS certificate while existing is valid

Tags: ios, xcode

Apple has modified some entitlements related to beta reports in September 2014. My iOS dev. certificate was created in May 2014 so I need to regenrate my distribution certificate. I have successfully generated new certificate and added to keychain. I deleted the prior certificate from keychain by right clicking on it.

[image]

I had project in Xcode for which 1.0 was published and now I want to publish version 1.1 for it. Code Signing Activity entry in Xcode shows iPhone Distribution with same id as shown in keychain 8XS.....
When I try to archive the project I get a code signing error:

```
D6C2B03C75C9F3735948BF4F1AA530FA3163070D: no identity found
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

How to fix it.

Comment: Did you assign your new provisioning profile on your project Target -- Build Settings -- Code Signing -- Provisioning profile ?

Comment: the provisioning profile is present in Build Settings of target and project both. I even choose Automatic and then reassign the iphone distribution profile again. But same error. Performed a clean also

Comment: You can right click on your .xcodeproj and open show package content then open project.pbxproj with a text editor and check "CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY" and "PROVISIONING_PROFILE" if it correctly set there.

Comment: Yes its set perfectly there. I just checked. One thing I want to confirm from you. In my apple console, I still have old certificate. Shall I revoke that. The old and new certificates are having same id 8XS......

Comment: I think it is very good idea that make all from scratch. Delete old certificate and your new provisioning profile from keychain and go to developer portal revoke a new certificate and create a new provisioning profile with this new certificate then you can eliminate all the other possibilities.

Comment: I hope deleting old certificates and provisioning profile will not affect the other apps published using the old certificate and old version of this app published using old provisioning profile

Comment: But you mentioned it is already expired. How come you can publish with expired profile?

Comment: no certificate is not expired but apple changed some entitlements related stuff in September 2014 which requires the generation of new signing certificate

Comment: Then you do not need to regenerate certificate. One thing you can do is a create a new project and try to sing with this new profile to see if the problem with Xcode or with provisioning profile

Comment: pls post I hope deleting old certificates and provisioning profile will not affect the other apps published using the old certificate and old version of this app published using old provisioning profile as an answer. Its working now

Comment: It does not affect already signed applications.

Comment: pls post your comment "I hope deleting old certificates and provisioning profile will not affect the other apps published using the old certificate and old version of this app published using old provisioning profile" as answer to this question